# Omnidirectional kinematic model in robot_localization's EKF

Tags: mobile-robot, localization, kalman-filter

I am looking for a more detailed mathematical background of [`robot_localization`](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization)'s kinematic model used for nonlinear kalman filtering.

From the documentation, the robot state used is:

$$\mathcal{X} = [p^W, q^W, \dot{p}^L, \dot{q}^L, \ddot{p}^L]$$

Where $W$ is the world reference frame and $L$ the robot local reference frame.

Of course,

- $p^\top = [x,y,z]$ is the 3d position.
- $\dot{p}$, $\ddot{p}$ its first and second time derivative (vel, acc).
- $q^\top = [\phi, \psi, \theta]$ are the usual roll, pitch and yaw euler angles.
- $\dot{q}$ its time derivative.

[By looking at the code for the position transition function](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/ros2/src/ekf.cpp#L259), it seems it's implemented something of this fashion:

$$ p_{t+1}^W = p_t^W + \dot{p}_t^W\Delta t + \frac{1}{2} \ddot{p}_t^W \Delta t^2,  \qquad $$

In this equation, linear velocity $\dot{p}$ and acceleration $\ddot{p}$ vectors are rotated from the robot's state variables, i.e. via a rotation matrix from robot frame $L$ to world frame derived from the estimated orientation of the robot $\hat{q}$, .

$$ p_{t+1}^W = p_t^W + R_t^{WL}(\hat{q}) \dot{p}_t^L\Delta t + \frac{1}{2}R_t^{WL}(\hat{q}) \ddot{p}_t^L \Delta t^2$$

The other transition funtions for the other states are:
$$\dot{p}_{t+1} = \dot{p}_t + \ddot{p}_t\Delta t$$
$$\ddot{p}_{t+1} = \ddot{p}_t$$
$$\dot{q}_{t+1} = \dot{q}_t$$

However I am missing the reasoning behind euler angles $q$ evolution from angular rates $\omega$.

At first, I thought euler angles were simply integrated from a gyroscope's angular rates

$$ q_{t+1}^W = q_t^W + \omega_t^?\Delta t $$

But clearly it's not what's being used there.

I cant' explain these relations:

```
    transferFunction_(StateMemberRoll, StateMemberVroll) = delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberRoll, StateMemberVpitch) = sr * tp * delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberRoll, StateMemberVyaw) = cr * tp * delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberPitch, StateMemberVpitch) = cr * delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberPitch, StateMemberVyaw) = -sr * delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberYaw, StateMemberVpitch) = sr * cpi * delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberYaw, StateMemberVyaw) = cr * cpi * delta;
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot that Euler angle rates $\dot{q}$ are of course NOT EQUAL to body angular rates $\omega$.
$$\dot{q} \neq \omega$$
Their relation, given RPY rotation convention, is

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{\phi}\\
\dot{\psi}\\
\dot{\theta}
\end{bmatrix} =
\overbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \sin(\phi) \tan(\psi) & \cos(\phi)\tan(\psi)\\
0 & \cos(\phi) & -\sin(\phi) \\
0 & \frac{\sin(\phi)}{\cos(\psi)} & \frac{\cos(\phi)}{\cos(\psi)}
\end{bmatrix}}^{T}
\begin{bmatrix}
\omega_x\\
\omega_y\\
\omega_z
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The derivation implemented in the code is correct.

Although numerically unstable for pitch $\psi = \pi/2$
, should be fine for UGVs..

Calling $T$ this matrix, we have

$$q_{t+1}^W = q_t^W + T\omega_t^L \Delta t$$

However, `robot_localization` does NOT sample $\omega$ with a gyroscope.